# Do I have to give my mailing address to create a certificate?

Tags: security-certificate, privacy

So, ICANN seems to require a mailing address for my domain, but my registrar (like many others) offers to proxy the mail to me to provide privacy.

However, when I want to create an SSL certificate, that also requires a mailing address.  What's the most common and acceptable way to keep my physical address private when creating a cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different SSL cert suppliers require different things. Each will require, at a minimum, the domain name being secured. Of course they will. A cert is designed to protect a specific domain name, and is issued for that name. So the domain name itself is not private. Why not simply use an e-mail address attached to that domain name?

EV (extended validation) certs give a lot of information about the organization which purchased them. Browsers will highlight sites with these certs with a green address bar or green lock. These are commonly used by financial institutions, as they provide verification of identity, so you know you're communicating with the correct institution. Normal (domain validated) certificates do not. The SSL supplier will probably ask for your name and address for their own files, and for billing purposes, but this data will not be included in the certificate.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the mailing address.

Comment: The supplier might ask for it, but it won't be included in the actual cert, unless you're getting an EV cert.

Comment: Ah, you're right!  I knew there were city/state/country fields in the cert, but those appear to be for certificate provider.  I guess I was paranoid.  Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: I added a paragraph, @JeremyStein.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I went with.  Please post if you have a better idea:

I took the proxy domain mailing address that my registrar provides for whois queries and I used it as my SSL cert mailing address.